# Retrieve data from multiple tables using Hibernate

Tags: spring, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

How can i fetch data from multiple tables in a database (mysql) using hibernate...
Can any one help me out in this regard... a sample example will be of great help, if possible.

Thanks.
Uday.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use some custom sql to pull from the two tables and then map the output of that to the entity in question.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-creating